# Ionic 4 => OSX platform

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic4, platform

I am working on an ionic 4 project and want to generate a version for the OSX platform.
I have successfully add the platform and build the project for this platform after upgrading to the last cordova version.
Now, i run the project for the OSX platform and i only get a black screen.
I had the information that we cannot generate a version of the ionic project for the OSX platform but after successed to add the platform i think that there are some new corrections in the cordova or ionic in recente version that my solve the problem.
Have any one encountred this kind of problem?

bellow is a config.xml file
https://github.com/zainebzaineb/project-ionic-osx/blob/master/config.xml

bellow is a package-lock.json file
https://github.com/zainebzaineb/project-ionic-osx/blob/master/package-lock.json

bellow is a package.json file
https://github.com/zainebzaineb/project-ionic-osx/blob/master/package.json

or can anyone help me get over this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add snippets of any configuration files / build files / etc. that you think might be relevant?

Comment: @Bwvolleyball bellow is a config.xml file https://github.com/zainebzaineb/project-ionic-osx/blob/master/config.xml

bellow is a package-lock.json file https://github.com/zainebzaineb/project-ionic-osx/blob/master/package-lock.json

bellow is a package.json file https://github.com/zainebzaineb/project-ionic-osx/blob/master/package.json